# Catching value of JOptionPane input dialog with preset choices?

Tags: java, input, dialog

I am using a JOptionPane with input dialog. I am having trouble catching the value of the choice so that I can use it later in my program.

```
    String[] options = {"Selection Sort", "Insertion Sort"};
    Object searchType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, null, "Choose a sort type ", 
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

[image: Input Dialog]

…and this is what it looks like.

edit: I am having trouble catching the option that is chosen by the user. 
I have tried:

```
    int selection = JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE;
```

and that will compile, however I can't actually use the value.

basically when a person selects one of the two options I want to know which one it is.

edit2: For future reference this works:

```
    Object selection = searchType;
    if(selection.equals(options[0]))
    {
        //something
    }
    else if(selection.equals(options[1]))
    {
        //something else
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify greatly the problems you may be having, because your question is impossible to answer as written, at least for me. More info and pertinent code, please.

Comment: I added what I am trying to do, there is no more pertinent code, I just want to be able to use which option of the two is selected.

Comment: "the showMessageDialog, showConfirmDialog, and showOptionDialog methods return an integer indicating the user's choice." Isn't it better for your purposes? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: @HugoSousa I may have to end up using one of those because catching the input is much clearer than what I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) a little close...

> Returns:
>   user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

This means, if the use selected `Okay`, that it will return the item the user selected as listed by the `options` parameter.  In your case this will be `Selection Sort` or `Insertion Sort` or `null` if they canceled the dialog

**Updated with example**

Using this and selecting [Okay] outputs `Selection Sort`

```
String[] options = {"Selection Sort", "Insertion Sort"};
Object searchType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, null, "Choose a sort type ",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
System.out.println(searchType);
```

Take a closer look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: I have tried taking the value as being a string, or one of the options through JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, but that only returns an int, and when I tested it I couldn't use the value.

Comment: Take the value that is returned by `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`

Answer (score 1):

You should check the object returned and compare it to the items held in your array.

Either that, or call `toString()` on it and use the String value returned to decide.

Comment: toString() won't work on JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, is there some other way I can get it to return my response?